# Twitter User Profile can be extracted by this

Tags: python, tweepy

I am able to extract the mentioned details about a twitter user using Tweepy API.
I want to do it for a list of users. Can anyone help me to this?

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
CONSUMER_KEY = 'ABC'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'ABC'
ACCESS_KEY = 'ABC'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'ABC'
class TweetListener(StreamListener):
    # A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream.
    #This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to standard output

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
twitterStream = Stream(auth,TweetListener())
user = api.get_user('User Name')
print user.screen_name
print user.description
print user.followers_count
print user.statuses_count
print user.url
```

This code is ready to use anyone can use it with his/her own credentials for a single user profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code simply interacts with *your* twitter account; to find information on a specific user or group of users you should look them up using the `api.lookup_users(user_ids=[])` query.

You'd do it like this:

```
#boring auth you already have
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
CONSUMER_KEY = 'ABC'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'ABC'
ACCESS_KEY = 'ABC'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'ABC'
auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)

#search
api = tweepy.API(auth)
test = api.lookup_users(user_ids=['1123728482,5539932'])
```

This gives you a list of two `tweepy.models.User` objects:

```
[<tweepy.models.User object at 0x103995090>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x1039950d0>]
```

You can replace the list in `user_ids` with a list of up to 100 ids, twitter won't let you search any more than that at once, though.  Once you have your list of `User` objects, you can access different properties (for a list, check out the tweepy doc for the [User class](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/models.py), line 113).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Luigi.I tried this but i am unable to generate the user objects

Comment: I have sorted out the problem for getting details for a list of user you can check the code above in answers@Luigi

Answer (score 8):

Finally exercising and reading a lot I get the answer to my question.you can try this

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
CONSUMER_KEY = 'ABC'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'ABC'
ACCESS_KEY = 'ABC'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'ABC'
auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
class TweetListener(StreamListener):
    # A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream.
    #This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to standard output

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status
#search
api = tweepy.API(auth)
twitterStream = Stream(auth,TweetListener())
test = api.lookup_users(user_ids=['17006157','59145948','157009365'])
for user in test:
    print user.screen_name
    print user.name
    print user.description
    print user.followers_count
    print user.statuses_count
    print user.url
```

This code is ready to use just put your valid keys in place of ABC & get the users profile.you need to get the IDs first.

Comment: I am trying to get user geolocation in similar way..  Can you please share some insights on that part

Comment: Hello Sitz, Please clarify what you want in your case. Geolocations can be extracted by geopy module of python. Google also provides its API for directly getting geocodes for any specific location.